# Un / Load ViewComponent Content in Modal OnClick

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

For example i have an Edit Order View and want to add articles or change the customer using a Modal.
At the moment i render the lists using a ViewComponent whích get the full list of all customers and articles inside the Modal (works fine). But now i realized that when i have hundreds of customers and articles i will always load everything inside the Edit Order View.

I there a way to load and unload the content only when i open the modal (preferably using C#)? Or is it no problem to fill the View with all this data?

Comment: Just use Ajax to load the data.

Comment: Instead of using `ViewComponent`, I will just implement it using iframe. You can style it to look it a modal. With iframe, you just need to define a new url that points to another action method that loads all customers and articles. It will only be called when the user clicks on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok got it run like this with a new frustating problem

First my Solution:

EditView (Where Modal has to PopUp)

The MenuButton

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal"  class="dropdown-item modal-link" data-id="@Model.Id" data-targeturl="@Url.Action("_CustomerListPartial","Customer", new {id = @Model.Id})">Customer</a>
```

At the End, the Modal:

```
<div class="modal show" id="signup" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" backdrop="true" aria-labelledby="CustomerListModal"></div>
```

The CustomerController

```
public ActionResult _CustomerListPartial(string id)
{
    ViewBag.id = id;
    return PartialView(customRep.ReadCustomerList());
}
```

The JavaScript loads the Partial

```
$(function () {
    
    $('body').on('click', '.modal-link', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.get($(this).data("targeturl"), function (data) {

            $(
                '<div id="modal-container" class="modal fade">  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" style="width:80%">' +
                '<div class="modal-content"  >' +

                data + 
                '</div></div></div>').modal();

        });

    });
});
```

The Table (Inside the PartialView) works fine.

My last Problem (and i tried absolute everything) is that i cant use BootstrapTable.
I already tried several positions where i included the JavaScripts.
And i tried to use this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#table').bootstrapTable();
</script>
```

I tried it in seperate PartialViews, _Layout, EditView.... everywhere
BoostrapTable works fine in "normal" Views or ViewComponents but not in this Partial!
Maybe someone has an idea...thanks in advance